# Can't find IPhone IOS Platform when creating a new flex mobile project

Tags: flash-builder, flex4.5

I am trying to create a new Flex Mobile project that runs on the IOS platform, using Flash Builder 4.5. After specifying the project name, The wizards opens the Mobile Settings form, where I am supposed to choose between two platforms, Google Android and IOS. Only Google Android is appearing in the Platform Drop down list, What could be the problem? I am running a newly installed version of Flash Builder 4.5

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update to Flash Builder 4.5.1, download an updater from [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/downloads_updaters.html).

Answer (score 0):

To configure your iOS platform, follow these instructions:

- press Run-> Debug config
- display your mobile app in left side

Then choose your target platform in right side of this config window.

Next choose your Launch method:

1. iPad
2. iPhone4
3. iPod

Comment: I did so exactly, but still in the Target platform only Google Android appears! no IOS

Answer (score 0):

To Run configure your target platform in flash builder

follow these instructions:

```
* press Run-> Debug config
* display your mobile app in left side
```

then 
choose your target platform in right side of this config window.
if u choose ios platform to   1. iPad    2. iPhone4    3. iPod lunch method drop down list
Next choose any one your Launch method

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Article on how to configure Flash Builder for iOS Development from A-Z:

[Configuring Flash Builder 4 for iPhone/iPad iOS Development](http://jackofalltradesdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/configuring-flash-builder-45-to-for-ios.html)

Comment: Dead link. This seems like a reasonable alternative though: 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/multiplatform-game-development.html